# Sending parameters to a function

Tags: python

I have some parameters and a variable $x$. If $x=0$ I want to send parameters $p=(p1, p2)$ to a function $f(x, p)$, and if $x=1$, I want to send $p=(p1, p2, p3)$. Let's consider the type of parameters are also different in these two cases. How would a professional do that in Python?

Answer (score 0):

That's quite vague so I did this

```
if(x==0):
    p=(p0, p1)
elif(x==1):
    p=(p0, p1, p2)
else: # Other cases, so you have an assigned variable 'p' in case x is not 0 or 1
    p=0

def f(x, p):
    if(x==0):
        p0 = p[0]
        p1 = p[1]
        # What you want to calculate : Example :
        result = p0 * p1
    elif(x==1):
        p0 = p[0]
        p1 = p[1]
        p2 = p[2]
        # What you want to calculate : Example :
        result = p0 * p1 * p2
    else:
        # What you want to calculate : Example :
        result = p
    return(result)
```

Does that help you ? Is there still something you don't understand ?
If that's still bad, can you explain what your function `f` is doing ?